# dplyr - Join tables based on a date difference

Tags: r, join, lubridate

It's late and I can't figure this out. I'm using lubridate and dlypr.

My data is as follows:
    table1 =1 observation per subject with a date

table2= 1 or more observations per subject with associated dates

When I left join I actually add observations. This is because I have multiple records in table 2 that match the key. How can I simply make this a conditional join so that only 1 matching record from table 2 is joined given that its date is closest to the  date in table 1.

Sorry if this was verbose.

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code. So can others will get idea and give the solution.

Comment: Look for "fuzzy joins" or the use of `data.table::foverlaps`. (In other words, there is likely no easy way with simple `merge` or `dplyr::left_join`.)

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Please, [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] (inlcuding a sample dataset and expected result) - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the data.table-package to join. Use `roll = "nearest"` to get the nearest match..

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table( id = 1:10, date = 1:10, stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
dt2 <- data.table( date = 6:15, letter = letters[1:10], stringsAsFactors = FALSE )

dt1[, letter := dt2[dt1, letter, on = "date", roll = "nearest"] ][]

#    id date letter
# 1:  1    1      a
# 2:  2    2      a
# 3:  3    3      a
# 4:  4    4      a
# 5:  5    5      a
# 6:  6    6      a
# 7:  7    7      b
# 8:  8    8      c
# 9:  9    9      d
# 10: 10   10     e
```